# How to remove ruby completely from my linux system

Tags: ruby, linux

I broke ruby in my system by doing this:

```
mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.gz
tar xfvz ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p327
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The problem occurs in many different circumstances:

- Trying to acess IRB:

  ```
  $ irb
  <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
  from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
  ```
- Trying to install gems:

  ```
  $ gem install rubygems-update
  <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
  from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
  ```

I tried to use synaptic to remove all ruby related packages, and reinstalled it, but it didn't solve my problem. I didn't install ruby through rvm, I used rbenv:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.2.3
rbenv install 2.2.3
```

I also tried the purge command. I don't know what's happening. I'm very desperate looking for a solution. The directory /tmp/Ruby had been deleted by me... I deleted it using thunar.
Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have that `/tmp/ruby` directory, than go there and run

`$ sudo make uninstall`

This command will uninstall all previously installed files from that ruby. It usually installs into `/usr` directory, so if you had a system ruby (installed from Synaptic or `apt-get` (it seems you're using Debian-based system such as Ubuntu) could also break your system ruby, you need to reinstall it too. You can find out it this way:

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude # install aptitude for easy searching
$ aptitude search ruby | grep ^i # find all installed packages, containing ruby in their titles
```

In contrast, `rbenv` or `rvm` don't use your system paths for installation, instead they use your home folder and install to a path like `~/.rbenv`, but since you mess up your system folder `rbenv` may look to a different place (it's hard to say for sure what's going on right now).

After you've cleaned up your unwanted ruby installation, use [`ruby-build`](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#installation) to install desired ruby with `rbenv`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build # install ruby-build
$ rbenv install -l # list available versions
$ rbenv install 2.2.3 # install desired version
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: this didn't work :/ i searched all packages, reinstalled ruby and still get 
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
leo@leo-desktop:~$ 
trying to run irb

Comment: but you gave me an idea, i did the same thing that I had done before, and then uninstalled it using make and it worked...

Comment: I have a question still, should I use sudo to install gems? because it get this when i run the command without sudo "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.
"

Comment: If you use rvm or rbenv - no, you shouldn't. They all reside in your home folder and you already have all permissions for writing there. If you use system ruby itself which resides somewhere in /usr folder and is writable only by root - then yes. But it's easier and more flexible to use rbenv approach.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the compiled from source version you installed:

```
cd /tmp/ruby
sudo make uninstall
```

Then purge system ruby:

```
sudo apt-get purge
```

Then install [RVM](https://rvm.io/), close and reopen your terminal, and do `rvm install 2.2.0`

Comment: this could have worked, but i deleted that directory using thunar :/

Comment: @LeonardoDias Re-download it, ./configure then make it again. Then `make uninstall`. Looks like you already solved it though ;)